# How to use Google's geocoding service api in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to render the geocoding service google api mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) using VueJS. I am able to do the same thing using normal Javascript and HTML but not able to do same using VueJS. I am not sure how to render it using VueJS.

Here is my index.html code:

```
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>VueJS NodeJS and Express example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    <script async defer
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIkey&callback=initMap"></script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my MapItem.vue file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Mapping api</h1>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Geocode">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data(){
        return{
          item:{}
        }
    },
    methods: {

    initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
          geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
        });
      },
      geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: resultsMap,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
}
}
</script>

<style>

      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }

</style>
```

Nothing is rendered on my local server when I run it. Any idea?

Comment: It would be helpful if you are able to add all the console errors to your question as well.

Comment: sure. let me try out the change you told and update with that.

Comment: you managed to solve the problem ?, I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

one error i see is how you use `geocodeAddress`.

Use a arrow function `()=>{}` for the event listener callback, so that you can use `this` as the component instance in the callback.

And call geocodeAddress using `this.geocodeAddress`, because it's defined as a Vue method

```
    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
    });
```

---

When you are importing this scripts `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIkey&callback=initMap` (note the `callback=initMap`), you are telling google map that, after the scripts is loaded, call a function called initMap. This function needs to be in the global scope. But currently it's in the Vue instance.

So you gotta remove `callback=initMap` from the script tag. And call the `initMap` function yourself only when you need it.

For e.g., call it when your map component is mounted

```
mounted() {
  this.initMap();
}
```

Comment: still the same. In console, i get this error message:
`Kb {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Kb (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…aSwRTUupZPE6LanaujGTaQn08&callback=initMap:146:49"}`

Comment: The issue is that I am not able to invoke initMap() function from the google api script as is being done in the example given at geocode api.

Comment: I tried removing it from the place you told and call it explicitly when I click submit button on my webpage. It did go inside initMap() method now but doesn't render anything though.

Comment: nopes. This time I didn't get any console error. The previous error I mentioned was also gone now. Console looks error free.

Comment: hmm. you may try to find the `#map` element in chrome inspector tools and see if the map is indeed initiated

Comment: I don't think the map is actually initiated. I think it is not able to find google.maps component at all which is because it is somehow not able to execute the geocode api script which I mentioned in my index.html page I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that gmaps api and your component cannot talk.
The most easy solution:

1. Add the following lines to your component:

   ```
   mounted: function () {
     var self = this
     // makes the function initMap global available under the vue scope
     window.initMap = function () { self.initMap() }
   }
   ```

   and do not remove the "callback=initMap" part of your gmaps load script!
   and you should add a this before `geocodeAddress(geocoder, maps)` in your initMaps function:

   document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function()    {
         **this**.geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
       });
2. More complex option:
   Load the gmaps api script with vue like i described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45605316/6355502 and do as described in 1.

PS: There are the lines

```
 <script async defer
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIkey&callback=initMap"></script>
```

in your code, please remove the first line.

Comment: It still gives me an error and map do not comes up. The error is that it is still not able to find out initMap function.
`Kb {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Kb (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…aSwRTUupZPE6LanaujGTaQn08&callback=initMap:146:49"}`

Comment: Ok thats because you cannot predict when the async script loading is finished! It may end before or after your `mount` hook is called. Please check my Option 2 where the script is loaded manually and because of that predictable. With this technique you can ensure that the `initMap` function and the api are both available